# Unix sockets vs TCP sockets in docker

Tags: docker

It is written in Docker's documentation that:

> For this reason, the REST API endpoint (used by the Docker CLI to
>   communicate with the Docker daemon) changed in Docker 0.5.2, and now
>   uses a UNIX socket instead of a TCP socket bound on 127.0.0.1 (the
>   latter being prone to cross-site request forgery attacks if you happen
>   to run Docker directly on your local machine, outside of a VM). You
>   can then use traditional UNIX permission checks to limit access to the
>   control socket.

I don't understand what is difference between Unix sockets and TCP sockets. 
Especially, what is the threat described here:

> latter being prone to cross-site request forgery attacks if you happen
>   to run Docker directly on your local machine, outside of a VM)

?
Why running in VM is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cross-site request forgery attack happens when a web site or web-app tricks you (or the web browser, because of a bug) into targeting, in this case, 127.0.0.1.  When you're running containers on your own machine, communication between the Docker client and server is best served by Unix domain sockets.  But if you're running in Swarm mode with multiple hosts, you need to properly setup Docker to run over TCP and TLS for security and authentication.

There's nothing "important" about running Docker on a Virtual Machine in this context.  It's only needed on certain operating systems where Docker (or the images, in the case of Windows images on a Linux host, for example) cannot run natively.  It was the only way to run Docker on Windows and MacOS X before.